# PHP loop for number of posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, count

I need to create a slider navigation which has one `li` for each post. I currently have this code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'slides', 'orderby' => 'menu_order');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">

    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  $x = 1 ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $x ?>"></li>
    <?php $x = $x + 1 ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </ol>
```

As I need the first one to stay active.. But this isn't quite working for me

Comment: I'm getting one extra and they all say 1 so the number isn't getting bigger each time

Comment: because `$x = 1` is inside the loop

Comment: Why are you using $x = 1

Comment: @Anagio maybe she needs an iterator number for the slides..

Comment: I do need an iterator but it would probably be easier to loop through the post count? I just don't know how!

Comment: You can get the post count from your query object it returns the parameter post_count. Or use count($post)

Comment: shouldn't it be `$loop->post_count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

** take note that the $x variable was moved outside the loop so that your `data-slide-to` value will not all be equal to 1;

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <?php $x = 1; ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $x++; ?>"></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```

** if you are getting extras, it maybe because you have put a static

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
```

inside the loop, so what you might want could be this instead:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php $x = 0; ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $x; ?>" <?php echo ($x++==0)?'class="active"':'';?>></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: You should note that the primary difference here is that you are setting `$x = 1` BEFORE the loops, whereas before his code was resetting `$x = 1` which each iteration.

Comment: this works but I still have one extra, the `li` that isn't in the loop probably should be.. but I need it to have the class "active"

Comment: good thing i have edited the answer already.. i have just read your comment. pls tell me if it works now.

Comment: although you dont do anything on your loop.. you could put `the_content()` or something inside the <li></li> tags.. that's what you want to do i guess.. because the current code would generate empty <li>'s, if im not mistaken..

Comment: the code i gave will put the class="active" on the first element.. no need for extra variables.. ;)

Comment: sorry, i misplaced the iterator ($x++), i corrected it and it should work now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count like this

```
$posts = new WP_Query( $postargs );
$postcount = $posts ->post_count;
```

Now do `echo $postcount;` and you will have the number of posts.